# Web Deployment Manager "Unknown Error" (IIS7)

Tags: iis-7

I've been at this all day, trying to get Web Deployment setup on my server.  First off, I'm running IIS7 under Windows Server 2008 Data Center 64bit (on a VPS).  At first I thought I had it working, but it seems I was using the old (Windows Administrator login only) IIS6 stuff that comes alongside IIS7.

I've followed this guide perfectly, and I'm still getting errors:  http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/516/configure-the-web-deployment-handler/.

This is the error I receive (as per the directions at the end of the article): https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIbn6.png

Any help is appreciated.  I've tried everything (I've verified all the basic things like LOCAL SERVICE folder access, IIS Manager permissions, the service is active, etc).

Thanks, I know someone on SO knows this stuff ^_^.